# Error en URL de autorizacion de usuario en Connect

Tags: mercadopago

Estimados, estoy dando mis primeros pasos con Mercadopago.

De acuerdo a la documentación de [MercadoPago Connect](https://www.mercadopago.com.uy/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/mercadopago-connect/), los usuarios necesitan acceder a esta URL: https://auth.mercadopago/authorization?client_id=APP_ID&response_type=code&platform_id=mp&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.URL_de_retorno.com, reemplazando client_id por mi app_id.

El problema es que no se encuentra el servidor y por lo tanto no se puede redirigir al usuario.

¿Podria tratarse de un error en la documentacion?

Muchas gracias.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La URL de retorno también la tenes que modificar, sería la dirección a donde se dirige al usuario una vez que el usuario acepta darle permisos a tu aplicación.
En esa página te va a volver un código mediante **GET**

EDICIÓN:
La documentación está mal, la correcta dirección debería ser:

https://auth.mercadopago.com.uy/authorization?client_id=APP_ID&response_type=code&platform_id=mp&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.URL_de_retorno.com

Comment: He incluido la redirect_uri (que dicho sea de paso coincide con la redirect_uri seteada en la configuracion de mi applicacion). Pero el resultado es el mismo. Al parecer el error no esta en la redirect_uri. El Not Found es el siguiente: _Servidor no encontrado Firefox no puede encontrar el servidor auth.mercadopago_

Comment: Ahí miré bien, el problema es que está mal la documentación y falta el .com.uy en https://auth.mercadopago.com.uy

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues un ejemplo de lo que has respondido